# SQL group by and count

Tags: sql, count, group-by, sql-server-2012

I have following table:

```
OrderId   ContactId    IsPrimaryContact    FirstName
1         1            1                   John
1         2            0                   Steve
2         3            1                   Mary
```

I want to get number of contacts per order and retrieve only primary contact. Result would look like this:

```
Contacts  OrderId   ContactId    FirstName
2         1         1            John
1         2         3            Mary
```

Using SQL Server 2012

Comment: What database are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select x.contacts, y.orderid, y.contactid, y.firstname
  from (select count(*) as contacts, orderid from tbl group by orderid) x
  join tbl y
    on x.orderid = y.orderid
 where y.isprimarycontact = 1
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62149/2/0

Above answer assumes:
1. Each order can have not more than one primary contact
2. Each order does have a primary contact listed

Below answer would address the possibility of an order not having a primary contact listed (although the contactid and firstname fields will be blank, likewise):

```
select x.contacts, x.orderid, y.contactid, y.firstname
  from (select count(*) as contacts, orderid from tbl group by orderid) x
  left join tbl y
    on x.orderid = y.orderid
   and y.isprimarycontact = 1
```

Comment: +1 This is probably as close as it gets. It may be worth noting that if there are no contacts marked as primary, that order will be missing, and if there are more than 1 marked as primary, the order will be listed multiple times

Comment: problem could be in this line: `select count(*) as contacts, orderid from tbl group by orderid` since contacts table has millions of rows and this basically scans all of them

Comment: @hairraisin agreed although this should be handled at the application level. I added a 2nd query for addressing the 'no primary contact' possibility though.

Comment: @ile if you need the count for all orders on the table there is no way to avoid a full scan. You could get a performance gain from partitioning and running in parallel.

Comment: If you want to avoid a full table scan, consider denormalizing your data. Cache the number of contacts (as well as the primary contact name, if you desire) in the orders table. just be sure to update that every time a contact is added/removed/changed

Answer (score 2):

With `CROSS APPLY`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(OrderID INT, ContactID INT, IsPrimary BIT, FirstName NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'John'),
(1, 2, 0, 'Steve'),
(2, 3, 1, 'Mary')

SELECT o.Count, OrderID, ContactID, FirstName 
FROM @t t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM @t WHERE OrderID = t1.OrderID) o
WHERE IsPrimary = 1
```

Output:

```
Count   OrderID ContactID   FirstName
2       1       1           John
1       2       3           Mary
```